# exec linux command via php

Tags: php, linux

I'm working with a multimedia router with Linux Linaro as OS. I'm having problems when I try to make a red monitorization with iptraf. If I use `iptraf` in shell, it works perfectly. The problem appears when I try to run the same command through a php script.

This is the line:

```
shell_exec("iptraf -i wlan0 -L ../../../mnt/web0/mantenimientoV2/log2.txt");
```

As I said, this command works perfectly in shell and creates the log, but if I execute it with php, it doesn't create the log. I need this log, what can I do?

Comment: Is this via CLI PHP or Web interface?

Comment: if it's via web (eg. through your httpd) make sure the httpd user has write permissions to the log file / folder.

Comment: try using an absolute path so you know where the file is written

Comment: First thing you _always_ have to do in such a case: _look into your error log file._ That is where you can actually _read_ what the issue is instead having to guess or ask here.

Comment: sorry but where is error log file?

Comment: If you are running apache, it is either: `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/httpd/error_log` under standard config. nginx defaults to: `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: i have checked this logs and nothing appear....